# Save sessionId and update session variable in same action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-variables, sessionid

since I am new to this, I may use the wrong approach but my question is:

I get an async post from a third party to an action. In that post I get a user sessionId. How do I save sessionvariables to that Id?

If I do like this:

```
manager.SaveSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, sessionId, out redirected, out isAdded);


Session["test"] = "AAA";
```

It seems like Session["test"] is saved to the old Session.

**Update:**

This is beeing done:

1)I do post to a third party.
2) I get a url back and I redirect the user to that Url.
3) Fter the user press 'ok' on the third party site I get a postback from the third party site to an action. In this action I try to save a sessionvariable. But I see that the sessionId is different. I however get the correct sessionId as a postback variable.

Thanks/A

Answer (score 2):

[SaveSessionID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.savesessionid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not supposed to be called from application code which is probably why you are getting unexpected results.

I question why you would be trying to set your ASP.NET Session ID manually in the first place (sounds suspicously like [hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)...)? It's safer to simply keep track of your 3rd party session identifier in the active session e.g.

```
Session["3rdPartySessionId"] = sessionId;
```

---

> For some reason when I get the postback, my `HttpContext.Session.SessionID` is different from the user cookie

This is because you are using cookie-based session state. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> When using cookie-based session state, ASP.NET does not allocate storage for session data until the Session object is used. As a result, a new session ID is generated for each page request until the session object is accessed

The request in which you POST to the 3rd party API will not be the same request in which you handle the callback therefore in order to sustain the same session ID you need to *initialize* the session before you send the first request. Generally, the best way to solve this issue globally across your app is to initialize your session in the Global.asax i.e.

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // initialize the session object with "something"
    Session["Init"] = 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1711409 your update doesn't really change much from your original question. Why are you trying to change the session id?

Comment: For some reason when I get the postback, my HttpContext.Session.SessionID is different from the user cookie. Which means I cant save data to Session["test"] and later retrieve it for the user

Comment: @user1711409 are you using cookie-based session state?

Comment: cookie-based session state

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes I have seen this kind of problem being solved that way. But for some reason this did not work for me. I solved my problem persisting the data in another way. +1 for the solution that may help others.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though you are using SessionIDManager.SaveSessionID incorrectly:

"
This method is not intended to be called from application code.

The SaveSessionID method stores the session identifier in either the URL (when cookieless session state is used) or in a non-expiring session cookie.
"

Basically you are trying to set variables in someone elses session?